# Multi value Xpages extensions namepicker?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

How do I make the xpages extensions name picker multiple value?   I have it working just fine but only for a single value.   I am not seeing any multivalue property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under All Properties on the field you are writing the names to, set the multipleSeparator to use commas and semi-colons. Also set the multipleTrim to True to remove leadng and trailing white space. In the picker, users can select one name at a time, and as they add them they are appended to the list. Pressing OK writes all the selected values to the field.

Comment: Thanks that let me select multivalues in the box but if I do select multiple values I get "Could not save the document 90E NotesException: Unknown or unsupported object type in Vector".  I am using a multiline edit box and I entered a ; as my multivalue separator.

Comment: <xp:inputTextarea id="inputTextareaApprovingOfficers"
     style="height:55.0px;width:75%"
     value="#{document1.ApprovingOfficers}" multipleSeparator="/n"
     multipleTrim="true">


    </xp:inputTextarea>

Comment: Seems to work ok if it is an editbox but then the names all appear on one line.

Comment: How about writing them to a hidden field and then using a computed multiline edit box to display them?

Answer (score 0):

Add the Namepicker from Ext Lib.
Use Multiline edit box and use Multiple seperator as Comma or New line.
Regards,
Pranesh